# Symmetrical, adjustable voltage source from 0 to 15V, with adjustable current limiter up to 2A per channel

Tags: power-supply

I am a recent graduate in electronics, and I am working on an adjustable symmetrical voltage source with a current limiter that remains stable for any capacitive load. Since I am a recent graduate, I would appreciate assistance in analyzing this circuit. I would like to understand why the circuit oscillates when the output capacitors (C1 and C2) are removed and how these capacitors placed there ensure the stability of the power supply. I would also appreciate an explanation from someone more experienced regarding current and voltage control, as well as an overview of the general operation of the power supply.

Attached is the power supply simulated in LTspice and its corresponding library so that you can simulate it if you wish.

The complete power supply circuit (without the linear power supply) is used for simulation. I am still unsure why I can't simulate with the complete power supply circuit (with the linear power supply).

The entire library is too large to be shared here. So, I have uploaded it and the circuit to Google Drive, and I will leave the link here for you to download.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13cNf8YzybxsezZxV_cqKbCpJ0NyOv_CS?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome! Please _inline_ schematic and simulation results.